# I am getting a FileNotFoundException but the file is there

Tags: java, android, xml, file, android-intent

When I try to open a file that I selected via an Intent I get this error:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /document/primary:Android/data/com.oli.myapp/Files/test.xml: open
>   failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

I don't know why this happens. The file exists because I selected it. Here is my Code:

**File selection:**

```
Intent chooseFileXML = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(new Helper(FunctionsActivity.this).getPathToAppFolder());                
chooseFileXML.setDataAndType(uri, "text/xml");
Intent intentXML = Intent.createChooser(chooseFileXML, getString(R.string.importXMLDatei));
startActivityForResult(intentXML, REQUEST_CODE_IMPORT_XML_FILE);
```

**Code to get it:**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    switch (requestCode){
        case REQUEST_CODE_IMPORT_XML_FILE:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

                String Fpath = data.getDataString();
                File file = new File(Fpath);
                Intent intent = new Intent(FunctionsActivity.this, CreateActivity.class);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(file.toURI().toString()));
                startActivity(intent);


            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
Uri uri = data.getData();
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromSingleUri(this, uri);
String type = documentFile.getType();
if(type.equals("text/xml")){
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        if(inputStream == null){
            throw new Exception();
        }
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line).append('\n');
        }

        //Could read the file with no problems
        createWithXMLCode(total.toString());

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //TODO

    }
}else{
    //TODO
}
```

Comment: please, share your AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` gives you a `Uri`. What the user chooses through `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` does not have to be a file at all, let alone one you can access. In this case, you are getting a `Uri` back with a `content` scheme, which is very common.

[Use a `ContentResolver` and methods like `getInputStream()`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) to work with the content represented by that `Uri`.

Comment: But the type I set here chooseFileXML.setDataAndType(uri, "text/xml"); make the user only allow to select xml ?!?

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX: The XML that the user chooses does not have to be a file. Even if it *is* a file, there is no requirement that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` return you a `Uri` with a `file` scheme.

Comment: Ok I read the link you gave me. I am creating a contentresolver via a query. It expects a uri and some things I dont know. Can you help me by that?

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX: "I am creating a contentresolver via a query" -- I do not know what you mean by that. You create a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on some `Context`, such as an `Activity`.

Comment: Im trying to follow these 3 steps which are not well documented:
1. Call openInputStream() to get an InputStream to read in the content
2. Call getType() to get the MIME type of the data backed by that stream
3. Call query(), asking for the OpenableColumns, where you can get the size of the content and some form of human-recognizable “display name” associated with the content

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX: Ah. Actually, those latter items are more easily handled via `DocumentFile`. Call `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()`, passing in your `Activity` and the `Uri`. Then, you can call `getType()`, `getName()`, and `getLength()` to get those pieces of data.

Comment: but how does this help me? If you take a look at my onActivityResult you can see that I need a file of which i can read the xml-content

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX: Ideally, you fix `CreateActivity`. Pass it the `Uri` (without all the `File` conversion stuff). Have `CreateActivity` use the `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`, then pass that `InputStream` to the XML parser. This is not significantly different than parsing XML that comes from an HTTP request via a URL.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. Can you take a look at my edit^^. Is this an acceptable solution or is there a better way?

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX: That will not work well for large XML files, as you will run out of memory. Also, it should not be needed, as any decent XML parser supports parsing from an `InputStream`, so there is no need for you to read it all into a string in the first place. Make sure that you are doing this work on a background thread, as with any normal disk I/O. Otherwise, this seems fine.